# Summarize values by Category less or equal to Slicer value

Tags: powerbi-desktop

I have 3 slicers on my following data (Category1, Category2, Period) and I need a Card showing the Total of (Value) based on slicers, which is easy. The part where I need the help is to show a bar chart with Period on X-Axis and Values on Y-Axis. This Chart should respond to Category1 and Category 2 normally, nevertheless, all Periods lower or equal to Period Slicer should be shown on the X-Axis. e.g. if Period 2023 (2) is selected in the slicer it should show two bars providing total of (Value) for Period 2023 (1) and Period 2023 (2).

Category 1  Category 2  Period ID   Period      Value
P1  M1  1   2023 (1)    20
P1  M2  1   2023 (1)    30
P1  M3  1   2023 (1)    50
P1  M1  1   2023 (1)    41
P2  M2  1   2023 (1)    52
P2  M4  1   2023 (1)    36
P2  M1  1   2023 (1)    60
P2  M1  1   2023 (1)    47
P2  M3  1   2023 (1)    59
P1  M1  2   2023 (2)    83
P1  M2  2   2023 (2)    70
P1  M3  2   2023 (2)    82
P1  M1  2   2023 (2)    106
P2  M2  2   2023 (2)    93
P2  M4  2   2023 (2)    105
P2  M1  2   2023 (2)    129
P2  M1  2   2023 (2)    116
P2  M3  2   2023 (2)    128
P1  M1  3   2023 (3)    152
P1  M2  3   2023 (3)    139
P1  M3  3   2023 (3)    151
P1  M1  3   2023 (3)    175
P2  M2  3   2023 (3)    162
P2  M4  3   2023 (3)    174
P2  M1  3   2023 (3)    198
P2  M1  3   2023 (3)    185
P2  M3  3   2023 (3)    197

So, assuming I have selected Period "2023 (2)", it should show me following chart, which should be responsive to Category1 and Category 2 as well:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7SkT.png)

Please let me know if I need to make a measure or a calculated table (which I doubt because Calculated table will not respond to my slicer).
Thanking you in anticipation.

Ahmad